# N-Tier C# Master Detail

Tags: c#, sql-server, master-detail, n-tier-architecture

I am using Visual Studio 2010, Sql server Express Edition & C#.

I have develop a simple Master Detail application (mostly with the help of experts help from this forum) An Order system, and now I want to go one step further from simple application to N-Tier version.

Did some search on net and came up with Tutorial which guides me enough to create Order class which contains methods:

- DataTable GetOrders(int OrdId) Retrieve order based on ID provided
- int SaveData(string CustID, DateTime ShpDate, DateTime OrdDate) To save the order, This method has all Insert, Update, Delete command in it, using SqlAdapter.

Following the same pattern I've also created OrderDetails class for setting up line items for each order. OrderDetails also contains methods GetOrder & SaveData...

Now the main problem, what should I do to save the whole Order with OrderDetails? I know this is something I should wrap up in Transaction...But not sure how to do? any link/tutorial/sample/guidance will be highly appreciated.

I've not posted any code due to make this post clear...If required I will post the code immediately.

Thanks

Ahmed

Comment: Yes I think you should add some code and precises your question - what is your problem? Otherwise I would recommend http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is this WinForms application or asp.net application

Comment: You can check [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439688/Creating-ASP-NET-application-with-n-tier-architect)

Comment: @Jocke ok I will add code soon...

Comment: @Damith This is WinForms Application, and thanks for the link I am checking it.

Comment: @Damith I've checked the link, it is indeed a good article with sample code. It's for webform, but that's ok for me...as I've done most of what is says..Any other link for N-Tier with master detail??